# is there a method to collect data intelligently from website?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

i want to get data from this link https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView
the problem is to get all the tree, we should click on + each time and for each line to get the children node of the tree,
but I want to display all the tree just on one click then i want to copy all the content.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends what you mean by "intelligently". Not sure if that meets the criteria, but you might want to try this.

```
import json
import string
import requests

abc = string.ascii_uppercase
base_url = "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/api/tree/children/"
follow_url = "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui="

tree = {}

for letter in abc[:1]:
    res = requests.get(f"{base_url}{letter}").json()
    tree[letter] = {
        "Records": [i["RecordName"] for i in res],
        "FollowURLS": [f"{follow_url}{i['RecordUI']}" for i in res],
    }

print(json.dumps(tree, indent=2))
```

This prints:

```
{
  "A": {
    "Records": [
      "Body Regions",
      "Musculoskeletal System",
      "Digestive System",
      "Respiratory System",
      "Urogenital System",
      "Endocrine System",
      "Cardiovascular System",
      "Nervous System",
      "Sense Organs",
      "Tissues",
      "Cells",
      "Fluids and Secretions",
      "Animal Structures",
      "Stomatognathic System",
      "Hemic and Immune Systems",
      "Embryonic Structures",
      "Integumentary System",
      "Plant Structures",
      "Fungal Structures",
      "Bacterial Structures",
      "Viral Structures"
    ],
    "FollowURLS": [
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D001829",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D009141",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D004064",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D012137",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D014566",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D004703",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D002319",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D009420",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D012679",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D014024",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D002477",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D005441",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D000825",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D013284",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D006424",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D004628",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D034582",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D018514",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D056229",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D056226",
      "https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D056224"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you want all of it, just remove `[:1]` from the `loop`. If there's no entry for a given letter on the page you'll get, well, an empty entry in the dictionary.

Obviously, you can dump the entire response, but that's just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, some parts are a bit tricky but it manages to give you the tree:

```
import requests as r
import operator
import string

link = 'https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/api/tree/children/{}'
all_data = []

for i in string.ascii_uppercase:
    all_data.append({'RecordName': i, 'RecordUI': '', 'TreeNumber': i, 'HasChildren': True})
    res = r.get(link.format(i))
    data_json = res.json()
    all_data += data_json

# This request will get all the rest of the data at once, other than A-Z or A..-Z..
# This request takes time to load, depending on your network, it got like 3 million+ characters
res = r.get(link.format('.*'))
data_json = res.json()
all_data += data_json

# Sorting the data depending on the TreeNumber
all_data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('TreeNumber'))

# Printing the tree using tabulations
for row in all_data:
    l = len(row['TreeNumber'])
    if l == 3:
        print('\t', end='')
    elif l > 3:
        print('\t'*(len(row['TreeNumber'].split('.'))+1), end='')
    print(row['RecordName'])
```